# Cloud Composer - Fixes for deprecated beta API's on Kubernetes

Tags: google-cloud-composer

We are currently running "composer-2.0.7-airflow-2.2.3" on GKE v1.21.x.

Looking to upgrade to GKE v1.22.x there are warnings of deprecated API's no longer available in v1.22 being used.

Can you advise if Cloud Composer will fix / or has fixed the use of deprecated API's in any later versions ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message seems to be occurring due to the  deprecated APIs in Kubernetes  where Beta APIs have since graduated from Beta (v1beta1) to GA (v1) as given in this [documentation.](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/deprecations/apis-1-22#removed_apis_in_122)

According to this [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-upgrades-autopilot#auto-upgrade-version-selection:%7E:text=GKE%20may%20delay%20automatic%20upgrades), it should not affect Autopilot Clusters in GKE as whenever an autopilot Cluster is created,auto-upgrade is enabled on the cluster and the node pools by default which results in less distruption in the services.Since Autopilot clusters are enabled with auto-upgrade, they always run in the same version of GKE as the cluster itself.